# How can I Install digital certificates on Windows 10 Mobile using c#?

Tags: c#, ssl, windows-phone-8, windows-10-mobile

I found a few links on the same, but I think it is a manual way of installing certificates. I am interested in doing the same through code. Is there any way to do it?

Links:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/keep-secure/installing-digital-certificates-on-windows-10-mobile